# Not able to start Main Activity from widget in Android with intent contents?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I am trying to launch my Main Activity from a widget but also sending intent contents. The reason why I am trying to do that, is in order to launch a specific method from within the Main Activity (namely, voice login). Here I just created a Toast for testing purposes. So, inside the widget code I simply do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LogInActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("button_clicked","hello");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
// Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
// to the button
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pendingIntent);
```

and inside my Main (LogInActivity) I do:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            myIntent.getStringExtra("button_clicked"),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
```

but nothing shows up. The EXACT same snippet works when I call a secondary activity and respectively receive the intent contents from it. Any ideas on how to read intent contents from my Main Activity OR at least someone to tell me that this is NOT possible so I should find another implementation is highly appreciated.

Edit: Adding Android manifest entries and secondary activity details

```
<activity
    android:name="SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".LogInActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".TransactionActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_transaction"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

In my secondary activity, I simply call the same script in the beginning, I believe the rest of the code should not affect this point.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            myIntent.getStringExtra("button_clicked"),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
```

Comment: Do you get a null pointer on the toast? could you show what is working in your secondary activity and their respective manifest entries.

Comment: I get empty string from the toast.
However, you helped since I realized that my splash activity is my Main Activity. Still though, the problem remains, why wouldn't it be able to read the contents from the intent?
How would you like me to show you the secondary activity's work? Maybe a list of the methods should help? 
Also, thanks for your time!

P.s. I edited my question above ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. It seems that the problem lied in the multiple intents that were received by my main activity. I apparently read the wrong intent of those, thus the NULL value. I began to start how to make each intent unique but it seemed that merely a small line of

```
intent.setAction("my action");
```

in the intent creation made the trick, I guess it gave it priority when received by the LogInActivity? I am not quite sure but I at least I got to read the contents after all.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this in the widget

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, top.class);
i.putExtra("widget", "1");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imagebutton, pendingIntent);
```

and this in the main activity

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("widget")!=null)
{
Log.i("INDEX", getIntent().getStringExtra("widget"));
widget = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("widget"));
}
else
{
 Log.i("INDEX", "NULL");
}
```

so you can check if it's null or not
and in my widget it's working fine btw

Comment: INDEX NULL, it is from the LogInActivity.
INDEX 1 from the TransactionActivity.

Comment: what is the access attribute of the LogInActivity class?private?
or can you e-mail me your full source code?

Comment: thanks for your interest. However I just found a solution. It seems that the problem lied in the multiple intents that were received by my main activity. I apparently read the wrong intent of those, thus the NULL value.

A small line of 
intent.setAction("my action"); in the intent creation
made the trick, I guess it gave it priority when received by the main activity.

Comment: ah!that's also can be the problem,good luck then with your project!